# Can I have access to mapbox baselayer data?

Tags: mapbox

I am just starting working with mapbox and have a question. 
I want to know if I have access to information from the [baselayer](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-baselayer/), for example within a map view to get a set of all objects of type park, so I can do some analysis with them.

I am using Mapbox Studio and I see I can modify css properties using

```
#landuse[class='park']
```

Can it be done? Should I use mapbox.js or can I use this inside the studio? Is there an API call for this?

Comment: Open Street Map?

Comment: @mapBaker does Open Street Map provides an API to extract data? I cannot find it, but maybe I am not looking in the right place (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6)

Comment: Oh yeah there are many - are you planning on loading it into PostGIS, or working with shapefiles? Are you looking for a specific region or ...?

Comment: I want to dynamically compute some statistics based on current viewport, for example how many parks I have in the current view, average surface, calculate who is living in 1 km range of those park. My interest is in urbanism and I am doing a paper on parks impact in cities.

Comment: We're doing the same kind of work, but using a downloaded extract from Mapzen ... you can script updating the data, but in terms of dynamically querying the OSM source tables, I'm not too sure...

Comment: the data is there because is rendered, and I am just missing a way of extracting it  into a structured form

Comment: You can start here: https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts